# How to set HttpEntity in restTemplate-execute

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to set the httpEntiy in the restTemplate.execute Method? I have to put the Authorization in the header, so thats why I can not exclude it. As a ResponseEntity I get a InputStreamResource.

This is working without HttpEntiy set:

```
File responseFile = restTemplate.execute(
            uriComponents.toUri(), 
            HttpMethod.GET, null,
             new ResponseExtractor<File>() {
                @Override
                public File extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {

                    File serverFile = fileProcessHelper.createFile(pathToFile);
                    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getBody());
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();

                  return serverFile;
                }
             });
```

This is NOT working. Error is: java.io.IOException: stream is closed

```
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                uriComponents.toUri(), 
                HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, 
                InputStreamResource.class);


        InputStreamResource stream = new InputStreamResource(responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream());
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        respHeaders.setContentLength(stream.contentLength());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + stream.getFilename());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(respHeaders).body(stream);
```

Or is there a way to reopen the inputstreamresource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I found a solution:

in the RquestCallback you can set the headers:

```
RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {

    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {      
            byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
            byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
            String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
            request.getHeaders().set("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    }
};
```